# TS complains when I add custom function to String prototype

Tags: typescript

I've added a function to transform text to camelcase to String.prototype. TS complains with the following error when code is run:

```
error TS2339: Property 'toCamelCase' does not exist on type 'string'.

  console.log('**** ', element.toCamelCase())
                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Here is how I implemented: 
global.d.ts: 
[image]

```
declare global {
  interface String {
    toCamelCase(): string
  }
}

export {}
```

converter.ts:

```
interface String {
  toCamelCase(): string
}

String.prototype.toCamelCase = function () {
  return this.toLowerCase()
    .replace(/(?:^\w|[A-Z]|\b\w)/g, function(word, index) {
      return index === 0 ? word.toLowerCase() : word.toUpperCase();
    })
    .replace(/\s+/g, '');
}
```

I tried commenting String interface in converter.ts but it didn't have any effect at all.

Comment: Basically, I tried the steps in that post. It worked yesterday. But after restarting my computer, TS started complaining again.

Comment: remove export{}

Comment: @Dimava, didn't work

Comment: If it worked yesterday, but doesn't today, you must have changed something. Just restarting your machine typically doesn't change the behaviour of the compiler ...

Comment: I've shared my current code. It's exactly the same as the suggested solution.

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem; as far as I can tell, the code works as it's supposed to.  Please provide a [mre] we can use to demonstrate the issue for ourselves.  If you can't do this then I'm not sure how we can help.